# Android Corrupting my SdCard FILES

Tags: sd-card, files

Sorry but i need help :)

looks like my phone corrupting files in my sdcard everything i copy to my sdcard is gone when i instert it to my android. i have format it,chksdk, even buy the new one but yeah my android keep making my files in sdcard become corrupted and useless.For example i copy this film and all the film is good to go but when i insert it to my phone most of the film cant play the files and then when i instert it again to my pc. second picture is happen i have tried all method but nothing is works. Sorry for my bad english or i use bad word :).

@And yeah i already relfash my phone to new condition and its not solve the problem

[[image: ]1.[1]]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This thing happened to me, try formatting the drive in the phone itself. Then it should be good to go.